# Using Entitiy Repository in TypeORM Subscriber

Tags: typeorm

I would like to use the 'Promo' Entity repository in my 'AuthSubscriber'.

The reason for this is I would like to automatically generate a 'Promo' entity and assign it to the 'User' Entity on creation of 'User' entities.

When attempting to initialize the repository in the subscriber class I receive the following error:

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Promo" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?
```

Subscriber:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class AuthSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {
  promoRepo: Repository<Promo>;

  constructor() {
    this.promoRepo = getRepository(Promo);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return User;
  }
}
```

Ormconfig:

```
{
  ...
  "logging": false,
  "synchronize": true,
  "entities": ["src/entities/**/*.ts"],
  "subscribers": ["src/subscribers/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learned I can access the repository through:

```
const userRepo = event.manager.getRepository(User);
```

Comment: getRepository() is now deprecated. Any other ideas on how to accomplish this?